# Can I use lambda to compress all images under a bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

Can I use lambda to compress images under a bucket?
I can get the images under a particular bucket visa listObject. How do you compress these returns and write it in another bucket?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can absolutely use lambda. Try this library: [aws-lambda-image-compressor](https://github.com/dariospadoni/aws-lambda-image-compressor)

AWS lambda function to compress and resize images

This is a Lambda Function which resizes/reduces images automatically. When an image is put on some AWS S3 bucket, this function will resize/reduce it and save it into a new bucket. I have used it in the past and I loved it.

Usage

- edit lambda-config.js file and assign name, description, memory size, timeout of your lambda function.
- edit .env file with your AWS access data
- npm install
- gulp deploy

You can also try this other library which is more popular in the crowd - [aws-lambda-image](https://github.com/ysugimoto/aws-lambda-image)

If you really want to create something of your own and want a good start.
I would recommend these 2 articles that explain it very well -

[Image conversion using Amazon Lambda and S3 in Node.js](http://jice.lavocat.name/blog/2015/image-conversion-using-amazon-lambda-and-s3-in-node.js/)

[Automating Image Compression Using S3 & Lambda](https://www.aaronmedacco.com/blog/post/2017/07/01/automating-image-compression-using-s3-and-lambda)

If you are fine to use Amazon API Gateway then u can follow this AWS Compute Blog -
[Resize Images on the Fly with Amazon S3, AWS Lambda, and Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/)

Hope this was useful.

Comment: Hey, I want to efficiently upload multiple images to S3, while compressing them on the fly. What do you suggest?